# Dual reperesentation of finite group (Fulton, Harris definition), Antipode (Hopf algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I have two questions related to the dual representation of finite groups.

1. I have trouble in understanding the following paragraph from *Fulton W., Harris J, Representation Theory: A First Course*:

> The *dual* $V^*=Hom(V, \mathbb{C})$ of $V$ is also a representation, though not in the most obvious way: we want the two representations of
> *G* to respect the natural pairing (denoted $\langle\; ,\;\rangle$) between $V^*$ and *V*, so that if $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a
> representation and $\rho^* : G \rightarrow GL(V^*)$ is the dual, we
> should have $$\langle \rho^*(g)(v^*), \rho(g)(v)\rangle=\langle v^*, v
>  \rangle \quad \quad \quad (1)$$  for all $g \in G, v \in V, v^* \in
>  V^*$. This in turn forces us to define the dual representation by
> $$\rho^*(g)=\;^t\rho(g^{-1}): V^* \rightarrow V^* \quad \quad \quad
>  (2)$$ for all $g \in G$.
> **Exercise 1.1.** Verify that with this definition of $\rho^*$, the relation above is satisfied.

Firstly, I couldn't do the exercise, because, as far as I know, the following is true
$$\langle \rho(g)(v), w\rangle=\langle v, \rho^*(g)(v)\rangle,$$
since $\rho^*(g)$ is dual linear map of dual space. So, according to this equation
$$\langle v^*, w \rangle=\langle \rho^*(g)(v^*), \rho(g)(w)\rangle = \langle \rho^*(g)\rho^*(g)(v^*), v\rangle=\langle v, \rho^*(g)^2(v)\rangle,$$
and it seems like not the case. How do I get (2)?
Secondly, why do we require the equation (1), if we know from the finitness of the group that
$$\rho^*(g) := \overline{\rho^T(g)}=\rho^T(g^{-1})$$
since $g^n=e , \;\rho(g^n)=\rho(g)^n=Id$, and knowing, that, according to criteria, it is diagonalizable, so its eigen values are $e^{i\phi}$, we get $\overline{\rho(g)}=\rho(g^{-1})$.
(As far as I undestand, for finite vector spaces the following is true $\overline{A^T}=A^*$)
Where am I wrong?
2. Also I want to understand, what is the purpose of antipode (Hopf algebra). I know, that we define antipode $S$ for group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ as follows
$$S(g)=g^{-1}.$$
How do we define the dual representation, using $S$?

Comment: For the first exercise, your definition of $\rho^*(g)$ is not quite right: you need $\rho^*(g) = \rho(g^{-1})^t$ (invert the matrix, then transpose). This is because $\rho^t$ is not a representation: we have $\rho^t(gh) = \rho(h)^t \rho(g)^t$ since transposition reverses the order of products. Inversion also reverses the order of products, so by putting them together we get an honest representation.

Comment: Secondly, the complex conjugate of a linear map $f: V \to V$ is not defined canonically (at least, not as another endomorphism $V \to V$), so $\overline{f}$ doesn't make sense. In fact, the notation $f^*$ (as a Hermitian adjoint) does not make sense either, because we have not defined an inner product on $V$. The definition $\rho^* (g) := \rho(g^{-1})^t$ makes sense when $V$ is a vector space over any field $\mathbb{F}$: there is nothing "complex" going on in the definition. It does happen to be the case that for complex $V$, there is always an inner product where $\rho(g)$ is unitary...

Comment: ... and in that case, everything you're writing down makes sense. (The inner product is not canonical though, even if $V$ is irreducible, it is only defined up to positive real scalar). Lastly, if $H$ is any Hopf algebra and $\rho: H \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ is a left $H$-module, then the dual representation $\rho^*: H \to \operatorname{End}(V^*)$ is defined by $\rho^*(h)f = f \circ \rho(S(h)) = \rho(S(h))^t f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
If I understand you correctly, we can't write $$\langle \rho(g)(v), w\rangle=\langle v, \rho^*(g)(v)\rangle,$$ since $\rho^*(g)$ isn't dual to $\rho(g)$, however it is dual to $\rho(S(g))$?

Comment: We want the equation $\langle \rho^*(g)(v^*), \rho(g)(v) \rangle = \langle v^*, v \rangle$ to hold. By the definition of transpose we have $\langle \rho^*(g)(v^*), \rho(g)(v) \rangle = \langle \rho(g)^t \rho^*(g)(v^*), v \rangle$, and $\langle \rho(g)^t \rho^*(g)(v^*), v \rangle = \langle v^*, v \rangle$ for all $v$ and $v^*$ if and only if $\rho(g)^t \rho^*(g) = \operatorname{id}_{V^*}$. Hence $\rho^*(g) = (\rho(g)^t)^{-1} = \rho(g^-1)^t$.

Comment: Now it makes sense for me, thanks again